# How to compile Java into 32 bit?

Tags: java

No 64 bit odbc driver for ms access. Wondering how to compile java source file to 32bit... Any idea. I have searched a lot on google but couldnot able to find the solution.

Can anyone help me!

Comment: Compile your class on 32 machine with 32 bit JDK.

Comment: Java bytecode is architecture independent ... perhaps you're looking for a 32-bit JVM?

Comment: @ken : ya i need a 32bit jvm. But i use 64 bit windows 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing. The trick is to run it in a 32bit Java virtual machine instead of a 64 bit one.

Compiled Java is hardware independent and neither 32 or 64 bit. The JVM that executes the code is either 32 or 64 bit (currently).

Comment: Oh my god!! Its frustating :(

Comment: yea, you only find out about this stuff when you hit native code like the ODBC drivers that are only 32bit

Comment: Ya exactly !! Now its time to search for 32 bit OS, rather than doing database program in Java ^_^

Comment: @GroovyUser: Huh? The 32 bit JVM from Oracle runs just fine under 64 bit windows.  And why not use JDBC rather than trying to hook into an ODBC layer?

Comment: Monkey: He's probably using the JDBC-ODBC bridge, since there appears to be only one type-4 Access JDBC driver, and it's not cheap.

Comment: @Ken: what ken says is true.. I'm in that situation :(